# Vista: Administrator account cannot change or see system settings

Tags: windows-vista, user-accounts, uac

Running from the administrator account doesn't let me change or even *see* system settings!

Info:

- I'm logged into the Administrator account
- I've turned off UAC in the registry
- I've turned off firewall and windows defender (no AV installed)

If I try any of the following nothing happens:

- control.exe system
- Pressing network or sharing center
- Pressing any user access settings (can change password etc. from the command line though, and is allowed to change settings in the registry)
- Start windows update

There doesn't seem to be logged any errors when I try any of these things.

Running in safe mode doesn't help either.

This is running Vista Home Basic SP1 on an Advent laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. Reinstalled the OS, and now it works. It has worked for many months, so I hope it wont happen again.